# how to set "connect-redis" in typescript

Tags: typescript, express, redis, express-session

Now im following the Fullstack React GraphQL TypeScript Tutorial

I get trouble in connectRedis with express-session;;;

```
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";
import session from "express-session";

...

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
```

[ERROR]

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof session' is not assignable to parameter of type '(options?: SessionOptions | undefined) => RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/connect-redis/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionOptions | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionOptions | undefined'.
  Type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/connect-redis/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionOptions' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionOptions'.
    Types of property 'store' are incompatible.
      Type 'Store | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Store | MemoryStore | undefined'.
        Type 'Store' is not assignable to type 'Store | MemoryStore | undefined'.
          Type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/connect-redis/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").Store' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").Store'.
            Types of property 'load' are incompatible.
              Type '(sid: string, callback: (err: any, session?: SessionData | undefined) => any) => void' is not assignable to type '(sid: string, fn: (err: any, session?: SessionData | null | undefined) => any) => void'.
                Types of parameters 'callback' and 'fn' are incompatible.
                  Types of parameters 'session' and 'session' are incompatible.
                    Type 'SessionData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SessionData | null | undefined'.
                      Type 'import("/Users/jsyovo/Documents/2-MyRepository/2-ReactJS/14-reddit-clone/server/node_modules/@types/connect-redis/node_modules/@types/express-session/index").SessionData' is not assignable to type 'Express.SessionData'.
                        The types of 'cookie.path' are incompatible between these types.
                          Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

22     const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rolling back to

```
"@types/express-session": "1.17.1"
"@types/connect-redis": "^0.0.14"
```

I have similar problems, and rolling back helps, although I do not think it is a good practice. I believe something wrong about typing in the new versions of these package

---

Well, I tried using the newest packages again, and remove "dist" and "tsc -w" again. There is no such error. So not sure what exactly the mechanism is.

Comment: Tkanks Bro!!!
I change to old version then it works!!

Comment: I believe you just clean something like cache or dist, and it should work.

Comment: Removing yarn.lock and reinstalling deps helped though

Comment: `warning @types/redis@4.0.11: This is a stub types definition. redis provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.`

This is the root cause. Uninstall `@types/redis`, this problem disappears.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem but surprisingly enough (and honestly, not entirely sure why this is so but anyway..) keeping the "require" instead of converting to "import" solved this problem for me.
When I had redis setup exactly as the documentation from connect-redis, it seems to work fine but somehow converting to import created problems.
If anyone can explain why this is happening, would be much appreciated!

```
const redis = require('redis')
const session = require('express-session')

let RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)
let redisClient = redis.createClient()

app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
  })
)
```

FYI here are my package versions (all latest versions up to date):

```
"connect-redis": "^6.0.0",
"express-session": "^1.17.2",
"redis": "^4.0.0",
"@types/connect-redis": "^0.0.17",
"@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
"@types/redis": "^2.8.32",
```

I ran into this problem while following Ben Awad's Fullstack React GraphQL Typescript Tutorial on youtube and when i undid the import conversion, code seemed to work well lol

Comment: This worked for me as well! I would like to know 'why' if anyone had an idea?